# How to use triggers in laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, triggers, laravel-5.7

My code, using PHP artisan make: migration create_trigger command

```
public function up()
{
  DB::unprepared(' 
  CREATE TRIGGER roll_no BEFORE INSERT ON `students` FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
  SET @roll_num = IFNULL((substring((SELECT student_roll_no FROM students WHERE
    class_code = NEW.class_code ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1),-2) + 1), `1`),
    NEW.student_roll_no = CONCAT(
    YEAR(CURRENT_DATE),
    NEW.class_code,
    IF (@roll_num < 10, CONCAT(`0`, @roll_num), @roll_num) 
  )
  END;
  ');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to create a migration for a model event. Laravel eloquent has multiple events such as `retrieved, creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved,  deleting, deleted, restoring, restored` that you can easily use them.

first, you should create Observer for your model like this

`php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User`

in the UserObserver you can listen to any event that you like such as:

```php
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the User "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

after that you should register your observer to model in `app/providers/AppServiceProvider` boot method such as:

```php
public function boot()
{
     User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

for more detail visit [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events).

Comment: Model events are good, but they would not work if the records were modified by another application.

Comment: Is there any way to watch the records that are modified by another application i.e API ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:
please check your SQL syntax

```
DB::unprepared('CREATE TRIGGER roll_no BEFORE INSERT ON `students` FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            SET @roll_num = IFNULL((substring((SELECT student_roll_no FROM students WHERE class_code = NEW.class_code ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1),-2) + 1), `1`),
            NEW.student_roll_no = CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)),
            NEW.class_code,
            IF (@roll_num < 10,
                CONCAT(`0`, @roll_num),
                @roll_num
            )
        END');
```

for example please check this link :

[[https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-add-mysql-trigger-from-migrations-in-laravel-5example.html][1](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-add-mysql-trigger-from-migrations-in-laravel-5example.html)](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-add-mysql-trigger-from-migrations-in-laravel-5example.html)

i hope help you

Answer (score 1):

For this type of operation, laravel makes some technique similar to trigger(event). 
If you have multiple events then use Observer otherwise you can choose this solution.

```
// inside your model

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    // beforeCreate
    self::creating(function($model) {
        // do something with your $model before saving....

        // return true or the save will cancel....
        return true;
    });


    // afterCreate
    self::created(function($model) {
        // do something with your $model after saving....

        // return true or the save will cancel....
        return true;
    });


}
```